# Good way to find views based on culture info in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, globalization

Sometimes, .resx files don't satisfy all the g10n issues. We need a seperate view for some countries.

For example, for US we use View.cshtml, for Austrilia, we use View.en-AU.cshtml.

I can definitely build a piece of code to find file names based on culture info, but I want to check if there is any framework comes with .net or MVC3 can do the job automatically or with a simple function call?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245573/localized-views-with-razor/4246783#4246783